# How correctly use a service in a parent component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make a inheritance. Child and Parent components. And I want to use a service in a Parent component. There is a problem, when I try to input service in a Parent constructor like that:

```
 export class ParentComponent  {
  items: any[] = [];
  fooService: FooService;

  constructor(fooService: FooService) { // here is the problem with service
    this.fooService = fooService;
  }
}
```

Because compiler asks to make `super()` in a Child constructor.

`super()` without arguments makes an Error

When I put service in argument `super(fooService)` – it makes an error too.

How to call service in a parent component correctly?

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0ZPkvXde3lYhOmzwdJd5?p=preview) is my code.

Answer (score 0):

Always inject and use a Service this way. Then it get‘s imlicitly instantiated.

**Parent**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent', 
    template: '<child></child>' 
})
export class ParentComponent  {
    items: any[] = [];

    constructor(private fooService: FooService) { }

    // example
    someMethod(): void {
       this.items = this.fooService.getItems();
    }
}
```

**Child**

```
@Component(
{ selector: 'child', 
  template: '<h3>Child component </h3>' 
}) 
export class ChildComponent { 
    constructor(){  }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to explicitly add `private`. Typescript does that automatically.

Comment: @callback He is using a `parameter property` where it is needed to explicitly add the modifier. From the docs: Using `private` for a parameter property declares and initializes a private member; likewise, the same is done for `public`, `protected`, and `readonly`.

Comment: I hav tryed this way: https://plnkr.co/edit/0ZPkvXde3lYhOmzwdJd5?p=preview  But I still have Error in Child component when I call super();

Comment: Sorry, I‘m on a train right now. Bad network. Can you please put the code of your ChildComponent in this post?

Comment: `@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<h3>Child component  </h3>'
})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {

constructor(){
  super(); // Should I do this?
}

}`

Comment: No, that‘s the wrong approach. Please, look at my edited answer. — Parent / Child relation in Angular is incomparable to inheritance in Java. The Child Component becomes automatically Child when the Parent Component uses its selector in its HTML-Template. The rest is done by Angular.

Comment: You can use inheritance in Angular too, but it‘s actually seldomly necessary. Most of the time you‘ll use Parent /Child Patterns in combination with Services.

Comment: I understand parent/child in temlpates. But I need just inheritance using "extends".

Comment: Okay, got it. Please, have a look at this article then. https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2

Comment: PS: it would be kind if you could however mark this answer as solution, although the final hint was given by a comment.